# How to get Chrome Extension Popup.html to recognized the input value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Why is my input value not being recognized through the Popup.html?

```
  <div id="color">
    <div id="isfruit">yes</div>
    <input type="text" id="enterfruit">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="peaches.js"></script>
    </div>

function basket() {
      var yespeach = $("#enterfruit").val();
      $("Peach is an orage color.").appendTo("#color");
}

document.getElementById('isfruit').addEventListener('click', basket);
```

I tried doing it through inline jQuery however it doesn't seem inline scripts are allowed.

Comment: try plane/vanilla js in popup.js

Comment: The posted fragment of code looks fine so I guess the problem is something else. You can probably see it easily if you open devtools for the popup. It's a separate window so it has its own devtools. Right-click inside the popup, then click "inspect". Set breakpoints in code, debug it, inspect the values, DOM, see what happens when you click.

Comment: A common mistake is to load jQuery as a content script. They can't run in the popup so you should load it just like peaches.js explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that doesn't look right on your code is the append; For this kind of trouble you can see the console inside the chrome extension;

```js
function basket() {
      var yespeach = $("#enterfruit").val();
      $("#color").append("<div> Peach is an orage color. value: "+yespeach+"</div>");
}

document.getElementById('isfruit').addEventListener('click', basket);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color">
    <div id="isfruit">yes</div>
    <input type="text" id="enterfruit">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem: I forgot to put the jquery.min file into the Popup.html file.